# Using a double value in a Fractional[T] method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, fractions

I have the following function which generates a Uniform distributed value between 2 bounds:

```
def Uniform(x: Bounded[Double], n: Int): Bounded[Double] = {
    val y: Double = (x.upper - x.lower) * scala.util.Random.nextDouble() + x.lower
    Bounded(y, x.bounds)
}
```

and Bounded is defined as follows:

```
trait Bounded[T] {
  val underlying: T
  val bounds: (T, T)

  def lower: T = bounds._1
  def upper: T = bounds._2

  override def toString = underlying.toString + " <- [" + lower.toString + "," + upper.toString + "]"
}

object Bounded {
  def apply[T : Numeric](x: T, _bounds: (T, T)): Bounded[T] = new Bounded[T] {
    override val underlying: T = x
    override val bounds: (T, T) = _bounds
  }
}
```

However, I want `Uniform` to work on all `Fractional[T]` values so I wanted to add a context bound:

```
def Uniform[T : Fractional](x: Bounded[T], n: Int): Bounded[T] = {
    import Numeric.Implicits._
    val y: T = (x.upper - x.lower) * scala.util.Random.nextDouble().asInstanceOf[T] + x.lower
    Bounded(y, x.bounds)
}
```

This works swell when doing a `Uniform[Double](x: Bounded[Double])`, but the other ones are impossible and get a ClassCastException at runtime because they can not be casted. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How many different types of `T` do you expect? If this is a limited set you could consider making a `nextRandom[T]` function. This only works if you know what kind of `T`'s to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest defining a new type class that characterizes types that you can get random instances of:

```
import scala.util.Random

trait GetRandom[A] {
  def next(): A
}

object GetRandom {
  def instance[A](a: => A): GetRandom[A] = new GetRandom[A] {
    def next(): A = a
  }

  implicit val doubleRandom: GetRandom[Double] = instance(Random.nextDouble())
  implicit val floatRandom: GetRandom[Float] = instance(Random.nextFloat())
  // Define any other instances here     
}
```

Now you can write `Uniform` like this:

```
def Uniform[T: Fractional: GetRandom](x: Bounded[T], n: Int): Bounded[T] = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  val y: T = (x.upper - x.lower) * implicitly[GetRandom[T]].next() + x.lower
  Bounded(y, x.bounds)
}
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> Uniform[Double](Bounded(2, (0, 4)), 1)
res15: Bounded[Double] = 1.5325899033654382 <- [0.0,4.0]

scala> Uniform[Float](Bounded(2, (0, 4)), 1)
res16: Bounded[Float] = 0.06786823 <- [0.0,4.0]
```

There are libraries like [rng](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) that provide a similar type class for you, but they tend to be focused on purely functional ways to work with random numbers, so if you want something simpler you're probably best off writing your own.

Comment: Very nice and elegant answer! Thank you. I learned something today again :-)

Comment: I have a question though: Why are you using a pass by name (=>) for the function? You could also make it `a: A` and pass the function like follows: `instance(Random.nextDouble)`. Is that correct?

Comment: @avanwieringen If you made it `a: A` you wouldn't get a zero-arity function, you'd get the value that resulted by applying that function once. The `=> A` is necessary if you actually want different values for `A`. :)

Comment: Thanks! But this also happens when I'd pass the function _Random.nextDouble_ and then call it in `next` like `a()`?

Comment: You could also do that (with `a: () => A`) and it'd work the same way as the by-name parameter, except that you'd need the parentheses when calling it. By-name parameters are really only a light layer of syntactic sugar for `() => A`.